# MathGL display quality

Tags: plot, mathgl

I just started using MathGL with its Lua binding. I use the following code to generate a quadratic curve:

```
require("mathgl")
gr = mathgl.mglGraph()
x = mathgl.mglData(200)
y = mathgl.mglData(200)

xv = -1
for i = 0,200 do
    print(xv,xv^2)
    x:SetVal(xv,i)
    y:SetVal(xv^2,i)
    xv = xv + 0.01
end

gr:SetFontSize(3.0)
gr:SetRanges(-1,1,-0.1,1)
gr:SetOrigin(0,0,0)
gr:Axis()
gr:Plot(x,y,"r2-")
gr:Title("Simple Quadratic y=x^2","",3)
gr:WritePNG("out.png")
```

The saved out.png looks like this:
[image: Quadratic Curve]

The image does not look very sharp. The axis at some point is gray and double lines somewhere. Is there some step I am missing to make the image sharper?